# Xquery function for Xslt key function

Tags: xquery

I want to convert the xslt key function to a Xquery function .
Can anyone help me in this?

Answer (score 8):

**If we have an `xsl:key` instruction**:

```
<xsl:key name='someName' match="patExpr" use="Expr"/>
```

**and a call to the `key()` function**:

```
key('someName', someExpr, $someDocNode)
```

**this is equivalent to**:

```
($someDocNode//patExpr)[Expr = someExpr]
```

So, for any specific key, you need to declare a function (name it `my:keySomeName()` ) that returns a sequence of nodes and whose body is the above expression.

**Example**:

**If we have this `xsl:key` instruction**:

```
  <xsl:key name='kNameByVal' match='Name' use='.'/>
```

**and this call to the `key()` function**:

```
key('kNameByVal', 'Peter', $doc)
```

**then the corresponding XQuery function will have this body**:

```
$doc//Name[. = 'Peter']
```

In case the second operand of the `key()` function is a more complex expression, a function that calculates that expression must be passed as the second argument to your key-implementing function (so this is only possible in XQuery 3.0 and up) and we end up with something like this:

```
declare function my:keyNameByVal($funExpr as function($context as node()) as item()*, 
                                 $currenDoc as document-node()
                                )  as node()*
{
   $currenDoc//Name[. = $funExpr(.) ]
}
```

**A more traditional, non-3.0 way** is that the caller calculates the expression and passes the result of this calculation as the first argument to the `my:keyNameByVal()` function:

```
declare function my:keyNameByVal($useExpr as item()*, 
                                 $currenDoc as document-node()
                                )  as node()*
{
   $currenDoc//Name[. = $useExpr]
}
```

}