# Xquery for searching pair of cousins

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xquery

I have an XSLT document which does the work but I want to translate to xQuery!
I want to search for first pair cousin and second pair cousin. I think I just need to convert the xsl function in xquery but I am completely new to that, can anybody help me out
Any help will really appreciated!

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
 xmlns:my="my:my" exclude-result-prefixes="my xs">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:key name="kChildren" match="Child"
  use="../HusbFath/*/@Ref"/>

 <xsl:key name="kChildren" match="Child"
  use="../WifeMoth/*/@Ref"/>

 <xsl:key name="kGrandParent" match="HusbFath | WifeMoth"
  use="my:GrandChildren(Link/@Ref)/*/@Ref"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vDoc" select="/"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  First Cousins:
  <xsl:sequence select=
  "for $first in 1 to count(/*/FamilyRec/Child),
       $second in $first+1 to count(/*/FamilyRec/Child),
       $pers1 in (/*/FamilyRec/Child)[$first],
       $pers2 in (/*/FamilyRec/Child)[$second]
     return
       if(my:areFirststCousins($pers1, $pers2))
         then concat('[', $pers1/*/@Ref, ',', $pers2/*/@Ref, '] ')
         else ()
  "/>

  Second Cousins:
  <xsl:sequence select=
  "for $first in 1 to count(/*/FamilyRec/Child),
       $second in $first+1 to count(/*/FamilyRec/Child),
       $pers1 in (/*/FamilyRec/Child)[$first],
       $pers2 in (/*/FamilyRec/Child)[$second]
     return
       if(my:areSecondCousins($pers1, $pers2))
         then concat('[', $pers1/*/@Ref, ',', $pers2/*/@Ref, '] ')
         else ()
  "/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:function name="my:GrandChildren">
  <xsl:param name="pRef" as="xs:string?"/>

   <xsl:sequence select=
   "key('kChildren',
        key('kChildren', $pRef, $vDoc)/Link/@Ref,
        $vDoc)
   "/>
 </xsl:function>


 <xsl:function name="my:areFirststCousins" as="xs:boolean">
  <xsl:param name="pPers1" as="element()"/>
  <xsl:param name="pPers2" as="element()"/>

  <xsl:sequence select=
  "key('kGrandParent', $pPers1/*/@Ref, $vDoc)[1]
  is
   key('kGrandParent', $pPers2/*/@Ref, $vDoc)[1]
  and
   not($pPers1/.. is $pPers2/..)
  "/>
 </xsl:function>

 <xsl:function name="my:areSecondCousins" as="xs:boolean">
  <xsl:param name="pPers1" as="element()"/>
  <xsl:param name="pPers2" as="element()"/>

  <xsl:sequence select=
  "my:areFirststCousins($pPers1/../(HusbFath|WifeMoth)[1],
                        $pPers2/../(HusbFath|WifeMoth)[1]
                       )
  "/>
 </xsl:function>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The input XML file:

```
<GEDCOM>
    <HeaderRec>
        <FileCreation Date=""></FileCreation>
        <Submitter>
            <Link Target="" Ref="FM001"/>
        </Submitter>
    </HeaderRec>
    <FamilyRec Id="FM001">
        <HusbFath>
            <Link Target="IndividualRec" Ref="IN001"/>
        </HusbFath>
        <WifeMoth>
            <Link Target="IndividualRec" Ref="IN002"/>
        </WifeMoth>
        <Child>
            <Link Target="IndividualRec" Ref="IN004"/>
        </Child>
        <Child>
            <Link Target="IndividualRec" Ref="IN007"/>
        </Child>
    </FamilyRec>
    <FamilyRec Id="FM002">
        <HusbFath>
            <Link Target="IndividualRec" Ref="IN004"/>
        </HusbFath>
        <WifeMoth>
            <Link Target="IndividualRec" Ref="IN005"/>
        </WifeMoth>
        <Child>
            <Link Target="IndividualRec" Ref="IN006"/>
        </Child>
    </FamilyRec>
    <FamilyRec Id="FM003">
        <HusbFath>
            <Link Target="IndividualRec" Ref="IN007"/>
        </HusbFath>
        <WifeMoth>
            <Link Target="IndividualRec" Ref="IN008"/>
        </WifeMoth>
        <Child>
            <Link Target="IndividualRec" Ref="IN009"/>
        </Child>
    </FamilyRec>
    <IndividualRec Id="IN001">
        <IndivName>Fathers name</IndivName>
        <!-- This tag used for father of c1 or husband of w1 -->
        <Gender>Male</Gender>
        <AssocIndiv>
            <Link Target="" Ref="IN002"/>
            <Association>Wife</Association>
        </AssocIndiv>
    </IndividualRec>
    <IndividualRec Id="IN002">
        <!-- This tag used for mother of c1 or wife of h1 -->
        <IndivName>Mother s name</IndivName>
        <Gender>Male</Gender>
        <AssocIndiv>
            <Link Target="IndividualRec" Ref="IN001"/>
            <Association>Husband</Association>
        </AssocIndiv>
    </IndividualRec>
    <IndividualRec Id="IN003">
        <!-- This tag used for a child to h1 or w1 or grand son to gm1 or gf1 -->
        <IndivName>Child 1 name</IndivName>
        <Gender>Male</Gender>
        <AssocIndiv>
            <Link Target="IndividualRec" Ref="IN001"/>
            <Association>Father</Association>
        </AssocIndiv>
        <AssocIndiv>
            <Link Target="IndividualRec" Ref="IN002"/>
            <Association>Mother</Association>
        </AssocIndiv>
    </IndividualRec>
    <IndividualRec Id="IN005">
        <!-- This tag used for grand mother -->
        <IndivName>Grand mother's name</IndivName>
        <Gender>Male</Gender>
        <AssocIndiv>
            <Link Target="IndividualRec" Ref="IN004"/>
            <Association>Husband</Association>
        </AssocIndiv>
    </IndividualRec>
    <IndividualRec Id="IN004">
        <!-- This tag used for grand father -->
        <IndivName>Grand father's name</IndivName>
        <Gender>Male</Gender>
        <AssocIndiv>
            <Link Target="IndividualRec" Ref="IN005"/>
            <Association>Grand Father's Wife</Association>
        </AssocIndiv>
    </IndividualRec>
    <IndividualRec Id="IN006">
        <!-- This tag used for a child to h1 or w1 or grand son to gm1 or gf1 -->
        <IndivName>Child 1 name</IndivName>
        <Gender>Male</Gender>
        <AssocIndiv>
            <Link Target="IndividualRec" Ref="IN004"/>
            <Association>Father</Association>
        </AssocIndiv>
        <AssocIndiv>
            <Link Target="IndividualRec" Ref="IN005"/>
            <Association>Mother</Association>
        </AssocIndiv>
    </IndividualRec>
    <IndividualRec Id="IN007">
        <!-- This tag used for grand mother -->
        <IndivName>Grand mother's name</IndivName>
        <Gender>Female</Gender>
        <AssocIndiv>
            <Link Target="IndividualRec" Ref="IN008"/>
            <Association>Husband</Association>
        </AssocIndiv>
    </IndividualRec>
    <IndividualRec Id="IN008">
        <!-- This tag used for grand father -->
        <IndivName>Grand father's name</IndivName>
        <Gender>Male</Gender>
        <AssocIndiv>
            <Link Target="IndividualRec" Ref="IN007"/>
            <Association>Grand Father's Wife</Association>
        </AssocIndiv>
    </IndividualRec>
    <IndividualRec Id="IN009">
        <!-- This tag used for a child to h1 or w1 or grand son to gm1 or gf1 -->
        <IndivName>Child 1 name</IndivName>
        <Gender>Male</Gender>
        <AssocIndiv>
            <Link Target="IndividualRec" Ref="IN007"/>
            <Association>Father</Association>
        </AssocIndiv>
        <AssocIndiv>
            <Link Target="IndividualRec" Ref="IN008"/>
            <Association>Mother</Association>
        </AssocIndiv>
    </IndividualRec>
</GEDCOM>
```

Comment: what is a _pair_ cousin? It's not mentioned in your XSLT, is it? Could you supply an input XML (preferably with real names replaced by placeholders)?

Comment: Added the XML file under the XSL @Marcus Rickert

Comment: A) If you have something that works, why change it? B) Two thirds of your XSLT *already are* XQuery... so where is the problem?

Comment: @Tomalak I want to change the function that is in XSLT into XQuery Function and also the Key function into XQuery Function, please help me out mate! Thanks

Comment: @user2217997 You didn't really answer Tomalaks question: _Why_ do you want to change it? What is the benefit of this change? I also can't see much reason to do this switch as you can also simply invoke xslt processing from most XQuery processors.

Comment: @dirkk I was told to do XQUERY but since I can do in XSLT therefore I did it in XSLT but the final works needs to be in XQUERY.

Comment: Anybody can help me with that!  @Tomalak

Comment: @Dimitre Novatchev can you please help me out mate

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to convert your key function into XQuery function then please goto [Xquery function for Xslt key function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13793199/xquery-function-for-xslt-key-function) and ready out suggest solution.

Comment: I have tried to change the key function, since in teh XSLT I have merge the function I don't know how to do it in XQuery, Can you help. I can show you what I have done so far too.